# Is Admiral Raddus Related to Admiral Ackbar?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, rogue-one

The Star Wars universe has two memorable Rebel Admirals, Raddus and Ackbar. Both are Mon Calamari.

[image: Admiral Raddus and Admiral Ackbar]

> Raddus - Admiral - Mon Calamari - Rogue One
>
> Ackbar - Admiral - Mon Calamari - Return of the Jedi

Are they related?

Comment: I find that racist! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnrVF8uWMO0

Comment: Well, they're the same species, so unless evolution works completely differently in the Galaxy Far Far Away, they must have a common ancestor somewhere back in history, so...

Comment: I definitely feel like they came up with Admiral Raddus specifically because they wanted to have Admiral Ackbar in the role but not be required to have him say "it's a trap."

Comment: "Admiral" can't be all that common a first name.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### We don’t know, but probably not

While we have no explicit confirmation that they are *not* related, the odds of two random Rebellion Mon Calamari being related aren’t particularly high. We are dealing with an entire species, after all, one that has been seen on multiple planets, and has at least one that they call their own.

In addition, [according to Pablo Hidalgo](http://www.starwars.com/news/much-to-learn-you-still-have-10-things-you-might-not-know-about-mon-calamari), Ackbar and Raddus hail from different regions of Mon Cala.

> Yep, that’s right. Fans of the squid-like species can get excited for
>   more Mon Cal. New variations of the famous aliens will show themselves
>   in the next installment of the Star Wars franchise. These guys will be
>   even more adaptable and might look a little different. As reported by
>   Lucasfilm Story Group’s Pablo Hidalgo, “Rogue One will show us Mon Cal
>   from the colder polar extremes. Ackbar and the other ones we’ve seen
>   so far are more tropical (and colorful).”

Again, this certainly doesn’t preclude Ackbar and Raddus from being related, but it does make it less likely.

Comment: That explains the colour difference!

Comment: Raddus's eyes are also notably smaller than Ackbar's. That might also have something to do with the different living environments of the sub-species.

Comment: It's stated somewhere in the old canon that the Mon Calamari are quite common among the Rebellion because the Empire subjugated their homeworld early on, prompting the majority of the Mon Cal fleet to defect and join the rebels. I have books from before the prequels came out that state that many of the cruisers seen in the Battle of Endor were Mon Cal vessels, including Home One.

Answer (score -1):

The ship admiral raddus has is a mon calamari mc75 cruiser but home one is mc80 and the mc75 is made for poler areas. But raddus is a poler calamari making him no way near related to ackbar

Comment: Raddus is 100% not realated to ackbar because one of them has to be between poler and normal calamari

Comment: You might want to describe what you understand "related" to mean, and then relate that to your answer.